# NSTimeZone returns the same localized name from two different timeZones

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I have an app to calculate time difference between two locations, and I just realize choosing "Europe/London" and "GMT" both returns the same string "Greenwich Mean Time"

```
    buttonTimeZone.setTitle(timeZone?.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: locale), for: .normal)
    print("timeZone:\(String(describing: timeZone?.description))")
```

The button displays "Greenwich Mean Time", but I believe GMT and Europe/London have 1-hour time difference.

I added the second line, print, to make sure I choose two different zones when I'm testing. The time of testing is October 28, 2017.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Greenwich is on the outskirts of London so Greenwhich Mean Time (GMT) *is* London time. What you referred to is British Summer Time, which London uses between March and October every year

Comment: I just realized London was in Daylight saving time because the clock changed back just today. All I have to do is to change the style from .standard to .daylightsaving. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone.namestyle Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You should post your explanation and your solution as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized London was in Daylight saving time because the clock changed back just today. All I have to do is to change the style from .standard to .daylightsaving when it is DST.

```
    var title = timeZone?.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: locale)
    if (timeZone?.isDaylightSavingTime(for: dateTimeComplete!))! {
        title = timeZone?.localizedName(for: .daylightSaving, locale: locale)
    }
    buttonTimeZone.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
```